# How to find all subsets $Y \subset \mathbb R$ such that $Y \times Y \subset \{(x , y) : x^2 + 4y^2 \leq 1\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to find all subsets $Y \in \mathbb R$  such that $Y \times Y  \subseteq \{(x , y) : x^2 + 4y^2 \leq 1\}$

Can anyone please give some idea to proceed?

I think we have to consider all the squares whose  diagonals fall on $y = x$ in  the ellipse $x^2 + 4y^2 = 1$.

But I can not understand how to see them  properly.

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: You can't count the number of points on a segment.

Comment: It's still incorrect.  You can't write a subset $Y \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: All of the square $Y\times Y$ must be in the ellipse. What's the "most constrained" point? I'd suggest the vertices of the square. That should lead you to $Y\subset [-a,a]$. Find $a$.

Comment: $Y \subseteq [-\frac1 {\sqrt 5},\frac1 {\sqrt 5}]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $E:=\{(x,y) \mid x^2 + 4y^2 \le 1\}$.

If $A \subseteq R$ and $A \times A$ is a subset of $E$, then for any $a \in A$, $(a,a) \in E$ so $a^2 + 4a^2 \le 1$ and hence $5a^2 \le 1$ and so $|a| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ and it follows that $A \subseteq [-\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}, \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}]$

Conversely, suppose that $A \subseteq [-\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}, \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}]$.

Let $a \in A$ so that $|a| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}$ and so $a^2 \le \frac15$ and $4a^2 \le \frac45$ and hence $(a,a)$ obeys the condition $x^2 + 4y^2 \le 1$ and so $A \times A \subseteq E$.

So the answer is as Kavi hinted at in the comments

> All $Y$ that are subsets of $[-\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}, \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}]$.